# R: get rid of plots outside of axis

Tags: r, plot

Is there any method to keep the curves inside of x and y axis without changing the original data?

[image]

Comment: This is very strange! Could you please provide a piece of your code that reproduces this "error"?

Comment: Can you show some line of your data e how you're plotting?

Comment: How in the world did you get it to do that? Please provide a MWE.

Answer (score 2):

With most plotting methods, your plot will stay "inside the lines" **unless** you set `par(xpd = TRUE)` (or `NA`). So, you probably set that option (or passed it to your line plotting command. You can revert to the default by running the line `par(xpd = FALSE)`.

From `?par`:

> `xpd`
>   A logical value or `NA`. If `FALSE`, all plotting is clipped to the plot region, if `TRUE`, all plotting is clipped to the figure region, and if `NA`, all plotting is clipped to the device region. See also `clip`.

```
par(xpd = NA)
plot(1, type = 'n')
abline(h = 1)

p <- par('usr')
do.call('clip', as.list(p))
abline(h = 1.1)

## or equivalently
clip(p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4])

abline(h = .9)

## xpd is still NA
par('xpd')
# [1] NA
```

[image]

Comment: i did this example before seeing your answer which covers both xpd and clip, so you can rollback if you want

Comment: @rawr great addition, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! You are right. I set xpd = True in my code. After changing xpd = True into False, the plot is inside x and y axis.